# Conditionally executing a Gradle task from another Gradle task

Tags: gradle

Let's say you have a Gradle Task "taskA" and a Gradle Task "taskB". "taskA" shall execute "taskB" if (and only then) a directory "directory-xyz" is not existing. [Edit] "directory-xyz" will then be created by "taskB". Actually, "directory-xyz" is in my case a "JRE distribution" ("taskB" is downloading the JRE zip file and extracts it to "directory-xyz")

Something similar to the following:

```
tasks.register('taskA', Copy) {
  // ..
  doFirst {
    if (!file("directory-xyz").isDirectory()) {
      tasks.TaskB.run() // this is not working of course - but how can you make it work?
    }
  }
  // ...
```

How can this be done with Gradle?

Comment: What creates `directory-xyz`? taskB?

Comment: Yes, "directory-xyz" is created by "taskB". I've updated the question above accordingly.